# Core Data entity design for master-detail interface

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am developing an app with a master-detail interface which displays a list of products that the user can drill down into.  On initialisation, the app loads summary information for (1000+) products from a web service and displays it in a table view.  When the user selects a particular product, the app calls the web service to get detailed info for that product and displays it in a detail view.

I want to persist this data between sessions using the Core Data framework.

I can think of two approaches for modelling this data.

1. Use a single Core Data entity **Product** containing all attributes for this object.  When the table view is initialised these entities are populated with summary data.  When a particular product is selected, the remaining fields are populated for that product only.
2. Use two Core Data entities, **ProductSummary** and **ProductDetail** with a summary/detail relationship between them.  **ProductSummary** contains the attributes that are loaded by the table view.  **ProductDetail** contains the attributes loaded by the detail view.

What are the pros and cons of each option?  Option 1 certainly looks easier to code, but am I storing up memory usage problems for later?  Would performance be equivalent?

Comment: Premature optimisation. You are making your life complicated by separating what is inherently a `Product` attribute into a different entity. You will never be loading all entities at the same time anyway (or at least shouldn't) and managed objects that are not being used will remain as faults so you should have no issues with memory.

Comment: @Rog Noticed your comment after I accepted the answer below...  My `NSFetchedResultsController` is returning Products to my View Controller in batches of 20.  Suppose I scroll down to the bottom of the list of 1000 Products - will I have a maximum of 20 Products in memory at any time?

Comment: Hard to tell exactly how many will be loaded in memory because the fetch & faulting of objects happens automagically behind the scenes. I can tell you I have worked with tableviews of 4000+ items all fetched using CoreData and I don't even get memory warnings for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With as many objects as you are going to have, go with option 2.  Keep the data coming in and the attributes of the entity down to only what you need to display in the TV.  Set up the relationship to detail and load that when the detail VC comes in.

I am doing something similar except with ~4500 rows.  I only store what I need and then turn to the other entity for detail relating to the object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I think you're right - I was trying to get away with less coding!

Comment: No problem. One other piece of advice. If you plan on implementing search, make sure you keep the fetchlimit low while filtering the data. That will make the filtering much more responsive. I can show you what I am doing if you need me to.